# Surround cluster of zeros on map with polygon with no more than 8 vertexes

Tags: algorithm, game-engine, game-physics

On image map ( 500 x 500) I have only zeros and ones. Mostly everything is ones but I have couple clusters with zeros ( that represent obstacle so player cannot cross over, like hills). Obstacle can have arbitrary shape, so needing for simplification, I decided to find a way to surround every such obstacle with a polygon with no more than 8 vertexes ( surrounding polygon can have some 1s inside, but all 0s of the obstacle have to be inside that polygon). For every obstacle I need to generate one polygon. I can connect every 0 on the outer border of an obstacle, but it would produce polygon with n ( n >> 8 ) vertexes. I am seeking for any suggestion how to do this or a name of some similar algorithm.

Comment: What are you going to use the polygons for?

Comment: @GarethRees I need vertexes for kinda graph creation and path finding

Comment: 1. I have edited what I could decipher. But the sentence "I can connect every external 0 but it would produce polygon with n ( n >> 8 ) vertexes" is absulutely unreadable.  Why do you think it is **possible** to create such polygons for every shape and placements of obstacles? I would agree only if the poligons can intersect.

Comment: @Gangnus The naive polygon of many vertices the OP is referring to could be created by starting with set containing an initial pixel of the obstacle and then iteratively unioning all neighboring obstacle pixels to that set. From this set of adjacent pixel squares you would erase any interior lines and be left with the minimal (possibly concave) envelope where the segments are constrained to be only on the vertical and horizontal.

Comment: @PaolaJ. The names you are looking for are alpha-shapes or concave hull. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/concave-hull-definition-algorithms-and-practical-solutions for some possible answers and resources.

Comment: @A.Webb Yes, thank you, I see. Edited. I hope, now the QA is more readible.

Answer (score 3):

You should initially build **convex hull** of your cluster.
After this you can decrease amount of vertexes to 8 using following strategy:
[image]

You find cross point for any pair of connected points.
On provided image point 8 and 9 replaced by one 10, but increase polygon size.

**Note:** this approach not guarante that this polygon not overlap another cluster of "zeros".
Sometimes maybe polygon with 8 vertexes can't cover a cluster without intersection of another clusters.

Comment: A good start but this assumes the obstacles themselves are mostly convex. For example, a convex bounding polygon would prevent entry into the valley of a U-shaped mountain range.

Comment: @Tolja Thanks for answer, but how to find polygon, my obstacles are not always convex ( I edited question to clarify)

Comment: So what? Even if an obstacle is not convex, the polygon can be convex. Your task says not a word against it.

Comment: The problem is that in the case of a too sharp angle in the point "10" you will have an extra long star-ray-like vertex. It is not against the formulation of the task, but it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 1):

You could take for an obstacle the S, SW, W, NW, N, NE, E and SE furthest points and create an octagon set by segments passing through these points in the perpendicular directions. I.e. appropriately: W-E, NW-SE, and so on. I think, that would be the fastest and easiest algorythm, and on the contrary to @Толя's solution, it will never give you extra long star-ray-like vertices.